# has_excerpt() not working inside wp_query

Tags: wp-query, loop, excerpt, the-content

I am trying to check for an excerpt and if it doesn't exist then show the content but trimmed. Currently nothing is showing.

```
<?php if (has_excerpt() ): ?>
    <p><?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?></p>
<?php else: ?>
    <p><?php echo wp_trim_words(get_the_content(), 25); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

However, if I simply do the below then I see content. Is there an issue with my above code? This is running inside a WP_Query loop

```
<p><?php echo wp_trim_words(get_the_content(), 25); ?></p>
```

The loop:

```
        <?php $args = array(
                'post_type'        => 'post',
                'posts_per_page'   => 8,
                'category__not_in' => 4
            );
            $latestPosts = new WP_Query( $args );
        ?>
        <?php if ($latestPosts->have_posts() ): ?>
        <ul>
            <?php while ($latestPosts->have_posts() ): $latestPosts->the_post(); ?>
            <li>
           //The excerpt code etc. goes here
           </li>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
            <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
        </ul>
       <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Can we see the entire `WP_Query` loop?

Comment: @TomJNowell, have updated question

Comment: I have also just noticed something. This is only an issue for imported blog posts not using Gutenberg. If I go to the post it shows all the content inside a classic editor block. The blog posts I wrote myself with Gutenberg editor are working correctly

Comment: If the `else` shows nothing, then it's probably because the post has a custom excerpt, but maybe a filter is not returning anything back to `get_the_excerpt()`. So try `if ( has_excerpt() ) echo 'has excerpt'; else echo 'no excerpt';` for testing purposes?

Comment: Hmm. I tried this and it works as expected for posts I created myself with Gutenberg editor but for the imported posts which show a classic editor block inside Gutenberg, it is echoing out `has excerpt` even though there is no excerpt.

Comment: How about replacing the `echo 'has excerpt'` with `var_dump( get_post_field( 'post_excerpt' ) )` - what's the output? Maybe the excerpt is a *space*?

Comment: Get this: `string(7) " "`

Comment: Well then, no wonder. That is considered a valid excerpt because its length is > 0. I.e. `empty( ' ' )` = `false`. So you should replace the value in the database.

Comment: So, deleting all the empty space from the excerpt resolves the issue. But I wonder why all of the posts were imported with all that whitespace?

Comment: Not sure.. Maybe they were exported with the whitespace, or maybe the import plugin somehow added it.

Comment: Either way, thanks so much. This was doing my head in and you resolved it. Would award you accepted answer but you haven't posted one yet, only comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So we already resolved the issue via the comments, but I thought I should explain something:

[`has_excerpt()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/has_excerpt/) returns `! empty( $post->post_excerpt )` if the post has a custom/manual excerpt, so if the function is returning true when it should be false, then it's likely because the length of the excerpt in the database is > 0, e.g. when the value is a whitespace — `empty( ' ' )` = false. (But note that `empty( '0' )` or `empty( 0 )` is true)

So if that's the case, then you should fix the `post_excerpt` value in the database so that the function returns the expected value.

But as I said in the comment, I'm not sure why the excerpt was imported with all that whitespace, so I could only guess they were added during export or maybe the import, via a filter.

Anyway, I hope this answer helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

Iggy!

With WP functions, typically speaking the get_ before the function signifies that the call is made outside of the loop, and as such you need to declare an object ID within the brackets, like so:

```
get_the_excerpt( $post->ID )
```

If you're using this function within the object loop, you should just call:

```
the_excerpt()
```

Which doesn't require the object ID, because that is already making up the query.